# How to make autocomplete for undeclared libraries?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

How to make autocompletion as in goland?
For VSC.

[How do I need.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OUza.png)

[No good.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bl7Tj.png)

I have installed packages:

```
gocode
godef
golint
go-find-references
go-outline
goreturns
gorename
gopkgs
go-symbols
```

And configured settings.json:

```
{
    "go.toolsGopath": "/home/user/go",
    "go.gopath": "/home/user/go",
    "go.goroot": "/snap/go/3739",
    "go.buildOnSave": true,
    "go.lintOnSave": true,
    "go.vetOnSave": true,
    "go.buildFlags": [],
    "go.lintFlags": [],
    "go.vetFlags": [],
    "go.useCodeSnippetsOnFunctionSuggest": false,
    "go.formatOnSave": false,
    "go.formatTool": "goreturns"
}
```

Comment: Your shared screenshot shows `fmain` snippet which generates empty main func, which is handy. What happens if you type `fmt.`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within VS Code go to the extensions tab and search for "Go". There will be one listed created by Microsoft which provides IntelliSense. Install this extension and restart VS Code, you should have the functionality you are looking for.

Note: you will need to be in a `.go` file for the IntelliSense to kick in.

Comment: I have it installed. I was helped to turn on go.autocompleteUnimportedPackages.